# Integrate Photo Gallery + iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am making an app in which on one of the view I want to display photo gallery photos thumbnails. If I click on any image then It must get zoom, there is also accept and delete functionality on zoom view. If user want to delete the photo then It must get delete from the photo gallery. I have tried a lot to implement this functionality but unable to get the required output.

How should I integrate the default photo gallery with my app? Following are the images which make you more clear about the functionality I want to implement. How can I start to make this functionality?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi there is a good framework which is capable of this
[three20](http://three20.info/)

If you want other similar things goto [cocoacontrols](http://cocoacontrols.com/)

Comment: But I don't know how to use three20 in my app. Will you give me some idea.

Comment: http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/making-a-video-and-photo-thumbnail-gallery-using-three20-framework/

Comment: And also download their sample project

Comment: three20 is not a good framework... have you tried modifying/maintaining a project that uses it ? Its a pain in the rear

Answer (score 1):

Use KTPhotoBrowser

https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser